# Field with unique and auto-increments values

Tags: 7, database

I have a content type that in one of their fields need a value that is unique and auto-increment.
There are several obvious solutions:

- Use the node id that is unique and auto-increment.
- The [Serial module](https://www.drupal.org/project/serial).

The problem with these solutions is that they use the MySQL auto-increments.

Drupal, by default, auto-increments the node ID (nid) and other IDs by one digit for each piece of content you create. You can see this if you visit your site by the node ID path:

```
http://www.example.com/node/1
http://www.example.com/node/2
http://www.example.com/node/3
```

However, sites that use database replication as a backup strategy (is my case) often will have non-sequential ids, meaning that you could see nids jump by two or more digits.

```
http://www.example.com/node/10
http://www.example.com/node/15
http://www.example.com/node/20
```

The MySQL [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) variable determines how many digits to jump for each successive auto_increment value.

And then I have this problem:

How I can do to have a field with unique and auto-increments values?

Comment: Depends on place where you want your incrementation to be executed. You can use both hooks and rules variants but with rules you need to execute custom code to get max value of your field and for example increment it before/after assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it yourself in your custom form submit, lets suppose your field name is  `myfield` ( machine name will be `field_myfield` and it is text) and your content type is `news` ( change them with your data) 
first in form alter you can hide it ( it you don't want user see it )
Get idea from my code

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'news_node_form'){
        if($form['nid']['#value']){
          // if we are in adding new node hide that field and add custom submit handler
                hide('field_myfield');
                $form['#submit'][]='_my_autoinrement_submit_handler';
            }
    }
}



function _my_autoinrement_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
$lastValue=0;
// search for the last value 
$query= db_select("field_data_field_myfield","mf") ->fields("mf")
 ->condition('bundle', 'news','=')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->orderBy('field_myfield_value', 'DESC')
     ->range(0,1);
     $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
     if($result){
         //get last value entered before this
        $lastValue= current($result)->field_myfield_value;
     }
     // increment last value ( biggest one )
     $lastValue ++;
   //set it in node
    $form_state['values']["field_myfield"]['und'][0]['value']=$lastValue;

}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but in your code, when multiples node are created at same time, the field get values repeated, because the query is execute at same time and sometime get the same value.

Comment: @rpayanm yes this have this bug, but you notice that you think the same time means exactly the same time .If you found better solution please write down here to I learn it

Comment: I think that the solution is with [Queue](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7). Is usefully [this tutorial](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/drupal-queues).